# Return unique_ptr with abstract class inside

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, smart-pointers

I am trying to encapsulate details of the Engine implementation class. To do that I am returning `std::unique_ptr` of abstract class (`IEngine` in my case) instead of `Engine`. But I could not do that due to the compile error. I could return raw reference and it works but is that possible with `unique_ptr`? Thanks in advance.

```
class IEngine
{
public:
    virtual ~IEngine() = default;

    virtual void Start() = 0;
};

class Engine : public IEngine
{
public:
    void Start() override {}
};

class Car
{
    std::unique_ptr<Engine> m_engine;

public:

    std::unique_ptr<IEngine>& Get() { return m_engine; } // Here is compile error
};

int main()
{
    Car lambo;
}
```

Comment: note: always add your error messages

Comment: Whats the purpose of making the member private but returning a non const reference from `Get` ?

Comment: Without the error message I guess that the issue is trying to return a reference to a `std::unique_ptr<IEngine>` when the pointer is `std::unique_ptr<Engine>`. There is no automatic conversion happening here because the types differ. Besides, I don't think returning a reference to the unique_ptr is a good idea in this case either.

Comment: `unique_ptr<Engine> != unique_ptr<IEngine>`  so you can't just bind a reference to it (to return from Get)

Comment: What is `Get()` supposed to do? Transfer ownership? Only give (unlimited) access to the object in the class (kinda breaks encapsulation)

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<IEngine>& Get() { return m_engine; }` hands out the ownership of `m_engine` to whoever calls `Get`.  Compilation error not withstanding this is probably not what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::unique_ptr<IEngine>` is a different type to `std::unique_ptr<Engine>`, so you are asking to return a reference to a temporary object.

`std::unique_ptr` *uniquely owns* the object it points to, so even if you removed the reference, it would be incorrect to create a `std::unique_ptr<IEngine>` from the existing `std::unique_ptr<Engine>` that you presumably want to leave unchanged.

You shouldn't be exposing `std::unique_ptr` here. I'm not really sure you should be exposing `IEngine` here. I'm also confused as to why you need the concrete `Engine` type in `Car`, but the outside world needs mutable access to a *pointer to `IEngine`*.

I would instead expect something like:

```
class Car
{
    std::unique_ptr<IEngine> m_engine;

public:

    void TurnIgnition() { m_engine->Start(); }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to encapsulate details of the Engine implementation class.

Returning a non-const reference to a private member is rarely the right thing to do. In any case it is the opposite of data encapsulation. Once the caller has the reference they can do with it whatever they like. Returning a non const reference makes sense for convenience access methods like for example `std::vector::operator[]`. The purpose of `std::vector::operator[]` is not to hide the element from the caller. There are other ways to get your hands on it. Rather `std::vector::operator[]` is to make it more convenient to access elements. Encapsulation it is not.

It is also not clear why you want to return a `unique_ptr` from `Get`. When no transfer of ownership is desired no smart pointer needs to be returned.

> I could return raw reference

Yes, thats perfectly fine:

```
#include <memory>

class IEngine
{
public:
    virtual ~IEngine() = default;

    virtual void Start() = 0;
};

class Engine : public IEngine
{
public:
    void Start() override {}
};

class Car
{
    std::unique_ptr<Engine> m_engine;

public:

    const IEngine& Get() { return *m_engine; } // Here is compile error
};

int main()
{
    Car lambo;
}
```